# Check if a command was used at least once?

Tags: macros, luatex

I use LuaLaTeX, so Lua-based answers are welcome. I would like to know, for an arbitrary command sequence, can I make some function/command `\wasused{csname}` to tell me if a cs was used in my document? To clarify, by used, it may or may not be defined. I'm more interested if the cs was called at some point. I suppose one way would be to hook a counter in `\def`, or make some special version of it to do so.

Comment: You can realize that an undefined macro is used at some point, when TeX stops for “undefined control sequence”. If the macro is defined, TeX just expands it; if you add to the definition some code that will tell you that the macro has been used, fine. Otherwise you're doomed.

Comment: Thanks. So are you suggestion that the only feasible way to see if a defined cs was used would be to add a counter for the number of cs uses, and just check that?

Comment: you can not add a counter without changingthe definition, this may affect the behaviour in unexpected ways. Probably there is no change that you can do that is safe for any command sequence.  Eg to test if `\halign`  is used you would hav eto redefine `\halign` so it was no longer primitive

Comment: Don't overlook that there may be macros which process delimited arguments whereby components of argument-delimiters can be control-sequence-tokens that are never defined and that are never carried out. Usage as component of an argument-delimiter may turn a control-sequence-token into something indispensable although that control-sequence-token is never used in the sense of carrying it out.

Comment: it seems very unlikely that you need this for _every_ command. For specific commands such as checking a document has at least one `\author`  then direct checks are easy to add.

Comment: Probaably you can do `\tracingall` and parse the excessive .log-file. :-)  (That is more a joke than an advice.)

Comment: also define "use", if the document does `\let\zz\fbox   \zz{a}`  has `\fbox` been used?

Comment: I'm curious what your use case is for wanting to do this.

Comment: Edge case: What about randomness during compilation playing a role? E.g., assume one of TeX's (pseudo-)random-generators delivering an integer number in range 0..1 and TeX in case of 0 delivering the token `\foo` and in case of 1 delivering the token `\bar`. This way it may differ from compilation to compilation whether `\foo` or `\bar` is carried out or not.

Comment: What about usage via `\csname .. \endcsname`? If `\foo` is undefined, then `\csname foo\endcsname` is like `\relax`-primitive. Shall this case be taken for usage of `\foo` or shall it be taken for usage of the `\relax`-primitive?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a counter, and then use `\pretocmd` from etoolbox package to increase it every time a command is used.

Here is we count how many times `\emph` was used in the document so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{emusage}    
\setcounter{emusage}{0}
\pretocmd{\emph}{\stepcounter{emusage}}{}{} % increase emusage every time \emph is used

\begin{document}

one two \arabic{emusage} \emph{three} \arabic{emusage}
\end{document}
```

The document will typeset "one two 0 *three* 1"